# Atmospheric pressure and heat convection

Tags: convection

If hot air rises due to convection, how does it get colder when we climb mountains?

After some research, I found out that atmospheric pressure affects the temperature of the surroundings. How does atmospheric pressure affect the surrounding temperature?

Comment: See if the answers on [Physics SE: Why less temperature at high altitude?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/40949/why-less-temperature-at-high-altitude/40970) make sense.

Comment: Welcome to Earth Science Stack Exchange! You will get higher quality answers if you ask reasonably specific questions after doing a reasonable amount of research. If you type your question into Google, you'll stuff [like this](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/if-heat-rises-why-does-th/) that should get you started.

Comment: Technically atmospheric pressure doesn't affect temperature.  Changing atmospheric pressure affects temperature.